How to send a Proactive Message to a Teams Channel
I am trying to send a proactive message to a static Teams channel using the Microsoft Bot SDK in Javascript/Typescript.
I am struggling trying to figure out how to associate a message to the team channel since all the samples I have found so far deal with responding to a user message, as you would expect in typical chatOps situations.
I need to be able to create an endpoint for a 3rd party server to send a REST request such that the chatOps server would then trigger the Proactive Message.  Basically I have other servers that will do something and send an event to the chatOps server, and I need the chatOps server to then notify a channel of the event.  Eventually this will expand to a more typical chatOps application but this is the first iteration.
I put together a quick sample with the bot builder code
https://github.com/Chocrates/chatops-sample/blob/main/index.js#L79
Here we create a new endpoint and use the adapter to try to trigger the bot.  This seems to work so far, but I haven't been able to test it against a real Teams yet.
server.post('/api/proactiveMessages', async (req, res) => {
    // Route received a request to adapter for processing
    console.log('Inside proactive"')
    await myBot.teamsCreateConversation(adapter,"http://localhost:54956", "Hello");
    res.send(200)
});

Over in the bot I tried to create a method to handle this case
https://github.com/Chocrates/chatops-sample/blob/main/bot.js#L27
    async teamsCreateConversation(adapter, serviceUrl, message) {
        const teamsChannelId = "emulator"
        const conversationParameters = {
            isGroup: true,
            channelData: {
                channel: {
                    id: teamsChannelId
                }
            },
            activity: { text: message },
            bot: {
                id: 'd1c86990-1146-11ef-b537-a7ce13724f54',
                name: 'Bot',
                role: 'bot'
            }
        };
        let conversationReference
        let newActivityId
        console.log('Right before sending the message')
        await adapter.createConversationAsync(
            'd1c86990-1146-11ef-b537-a7ce13724f54',
            teamsChannelId,
            serviceUrl,
            null,
            conversationParameters,
            async (turnContext) => {
                console.log('Inside the callback')
                conversationReference = TurnContext.getConversationReference(turnContext.activity);
                newActivityId = turnContext.activity.id;
            }
        )
        console.log('After sending the message')
        return [conversationReference, newActivityId]
    }
}

Right now I am only testing with the Bot Framework Emulator but in practice we will pass in the Teams Channel a more correct way.
Also at the moment I am only concerned with Microsoft Teams communication.  I know that Bot SDK is intended to work with many different messaging applications.
Edit:  Getting closer, updated the snippets above.  Right now it is hanging on the call to createConversastionAsync which could make sense.  I don't see a message in my emulator but it might not be set up for this.
Also I hooked up nc to watch that port and indeed got a message
[chatops-sample] nc -l 54956                                                                         
POST /v3/conversations HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
accept: */*
User-Agent: Microsoft-BotFramework/3.1 botframework-connector/4.22.2 core-http/3.0.4 Node/v21.7.3 OS/(arm64-Darwin-23.4.0)
Content-Length: 152
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Host: localhost:54956
Connection: keep-alive

{"isGroup":true,"bot":{"id":"d1c86990-1146-11ef-b537-a7ce13724f54","name":"Bot","role":"bot"},"activity":{},"channelData":{"channel":{"id":"emulator"}}}


You must create the conversation before sending the message. That conversation id you can use it for the proactive notification

Any clue how i start a conversation with a channel?  I'll go see if i can dig up the api docs for it.

Once you install the Teams bot, it will create a conversational ID, and it will persist until the app is deleted. You can refer Microsoft doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet

Thanks @RajeeshMenoth,  I think at this point I have a potential solution and I need to either get enough access to test it (working on it internally) or have someone authoritative tell me what the right way to do it is.

I have provided a detailed description in the answer. You should validate this approach in Teams or configure a ngrok tunnel to test it. However, it is important to ensure that you store the conversation reference in order to properly validate this approach.

It is explicitly mentioned in the following GitHub thread discussion that the proactive notification feature won't work in the emulator channel in the local environment.

So in order for the Proactive Notification to work, the bot that'll
receive the notification which will then send the message to the user
is the cloud-hosted one. When you're using an emulator, you wouldn't
be able to receive the notification because you're connected to the
local bot which the Directline API (the code that sends the
notification to the bot) doesn't have any idea about. One thing you
could use to fix this is to use ngrok for your local hosted bot and
change the bot's endpoint setting to be the ngrok URL. This way the
Directline API will be able to send the message to your local bot with
the help of ngrok tunneling and you would be able to see the
notification in emulator.

Note: Try this approach in a Microsoft Teams channel instead of using the local emulator.
I can suggest a solution that I have already implemented and tested, which could be helpful for your testing process.

Store each individual user's conversationReference in a blob or any storage medium using a unique identifier such as a user ID or any other key associated with the user.

Each file name under the blob should be the unique identifier name, such as the user ID, so that you can easily retrieve each user's conversationReference details by their user id. E.g Blob -> User123 ( File Name ) -> conversationReference

To handle the retrieval and sending process, you can create a separate web API that triggers proactive notifications ( This will fetch stored conversation reference in a blob, as mentioned in the above points ) or you can obtain the conversation reference through your code mentioned above and utilize Microsoft's provided sample code for proactive notification. Please note that this method will only work in a published app and not in a local environment as highlighted above. If you're using an emulator, you'll need to test it out using ngrok.

To successfully send a notification, it's necessary to have Teams Bot (Your App) installed. Without the bot, the notification will not go through. It's crucial to ensure that Teams Bot (Your App) is installed and not only relying on clicking on bot services channels within a Teams channel, as this method will not be effective.


Sample Code: Code Reference
await context.adapter.continueConversation(conversationReference, async (context) => {
             await context.sendActivity("Proactive hello.");
         });


Thank you Rajeesh!  I haven't had a chance to go through this yet but I'll mark it once i do.  Likely Monday.

The main problem I am having right now @Rajeesh is that I won't have a conversationReference.  I need to send a proactive message to a channel unrelated to any previous conversation users may have had with the bot.  Any idea about that part?

@Chris the bot can definitely start the engagement, either by replying to an existing message in a group chat or starting a completely new thread in the chat. However, it does require to have been installed initially, either by a user or programmatically, you can try out this approach without code - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-copilot-studio/advanced-proactive-message

To send proactive notifications without storing conversationReference, then you can refer to the link mentioned in the comment. However, if you want to send notifications through the bot framework, you need to store the conversation reference in a storage medium, etc. In case the bot is already with existing users and you don't have the conversation reference, you will need to send notifications at the Office 365 team level.

Haven't forgotten about this. I have resorted to the graph api to create a team and a channel and now trying to get the bot to talk to it.  still no luck.  I'll make sure this all gets updated when I find the solution.

Small update, graph api does not work in this scenario.  In order to send a message as the bot you MUST use the Bot Framework SDK unless you want to use the bought through a delegation flow but that would make the message as being from the delegated user.
